# Is the problem about Datastage Message Handler?

Tags: datastage

I have a problem about message handler on IBM Datastage.  I am trying to suppress this message: ""no more conversion warnings will be issued" . I added to Message Handler at project level. But when I run the job, it gives the warning message again.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Message handler only work for Parallel jobs - what is your job type?
Have you added the message handler in the administrator client?

If yes follow these steps:

1. In the job log check the second entry „Attached Message Handlers:“ and check if the message handler is active.
2. Open the message with the warning and check the message ID and compare it to the one of your message handler - the need tobe identical